recursion inside for loop with no change or arguments
I have this simple piece of code which is just a template and doesn't work, but should be the basis of what I want to achieve:
def to_s(x):
    return str(x * 2)

def f(x):
    print(x + "_string")
    x_set = [2,3,4,5]
    for i in x_set:
        var = to_s(x)
        f(var)
f(str(1))

I am stuck at the logic of recursion here, specifically how to determine the base case.
I want to implement it using recursion so that I can have the following output:
"1_string"
"4_string"
"6_string"
"8_string"
"10_string"


The output can have any order, and

I need only one print statement.


The problem is with the iteration from the start of the for loop within nested recursive calls. We could have an expanded version like what I did:
def to_s(x):
    return str(x * 2)

x_set = [2,3,4,5]
def f(x, n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    if n == len(x_set):
        print(x + "_string")
    var = to_s(x_set[n-1])
    f(var, n-1)
    if n < len(x_set):
        print(x + "_string")
        
f(str(1), len(x_set))

But that's not what I am interested in, is there a simpler way to do it without adding the addtional n parameter and getting the x_set out?
Update
I have a more complicated computation going on, I just replaced it by print(x + "_string") for simplicity, so the reason for recusion is that I don't want to duplicate code and recursion looks perfect to me in my situation.

I don't understand what you are trying to use recursion for.

I still don't understand. Do you want to use recursion to replace a for loop?

It is a general question, the logic is clear, how to go over elements of x_set with recursion without having x_set outside of the function, and without adding n

To satisfy both of your requirements:

The output can have any order, and I need only one print statement.

plus retain your helper function but keep it simple, I'd do something like:
def two_s(x):
    return str(x * 2)

def f(x, first=True):
    if x:
        print(("1" if first else two_s(x.pop())) + "_string")

        f(x, False)

x_set = [2, 3, 4, 5]

f(x_set)


If you want to traverse a list using recursion you can something like:
def f(x):
    if x == []:
        print('1_str')
        return 0
     print(str(x[0] * 2) + '_str')
     f(x[1:])

x = [2,3,4,5]
f(x)

But this is ineffective, taking a slice is an expensive operation.
It is faster to parse a list in reverse order.
def f(x):
    if x == []:
        print('1_str')
        return 0
    print(str(x[-1] * 2) + '_str')
    x.pop()
    f(x)


